# What could be null here?

Tags: c#, generics, null, windows-store-apps, argumentnullexception

My app is crashing after I clear the Bing Map of its pushpins and then open a flyout. This is what I see in the debugger:

[image]

The textblock is definitely not null - it is defined declaratively in XAML.

The List of String (CurrentlyMappedPhotosets) is not null - as you can see, it contains a string / has a count of 1.

The code just before what's seen on the scream shot is:

```
int count = App.CurrentlyMappedPhotosets.Count;
```

What could be null here?

Just before this happens, I call ClearMap:

```
private void ClearMap()
{
    var mapLayerChildren = from c in DataLayer.Children select c;
    var kinderGarten = mapLayerChildren.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < kinderGarten.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (kinderGarten[i] is Pushpin)
        {
            DataLayer.Children.Remove(kinderGarten[i]);
        }
    }

    CloseInfobox();

    App.CurrentlyMappedPhotosets.Clear(); 
    if (null != App.photosetLocationCollection)
    {
        App.photosetLocationCollection.Clear();
    }
    appbarbtnClearMap.IsEnabled = false;
    UpdateGUI(false);
}
```

...which calls UpdateGUI():

```
private void UpdateGUI(bool resizeMap)
{
    appbarbtnRenamePhotoset.IsEnabled = App.CurrentlyMappedPhotosets.Count > 0;
    if (resizeMap)
    {
        ResizeMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like `App.CurrentlyMappedPhotosets[0]` is `null`

Comment: App is the app itself, how it represents itself in App.xaml.cs

Comment: Is CurrentlyMappedPhotosets a list or another dataset? It might be that data is saved at index 3 or 5 or etc.

Comment: what is the `value` of `App.CurrentlyMappedPhotosets[0]` can you check it ?

Comment: @Vajura: CurrentlyMappedPhotosets is a List<String>

Comment: @GrantWinney: There is, apparently, an element in App.CurrentlyMappedPhotosets, based on getting to this place in the code and the Count value. Somehow an element is getting written into the List<String>, but element 0 is being left empty...could it be that it is an Empty String, and that's viewed as "null"?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon a empty string isnt null, a unassigned string is null i suppose but i think you would get a error before that. Is it possible that textblock0 is null? Check with if(textblock0 == null)

Comment: @Vajura: No, as I wrote in the question, textBlock0 is defined declaratively, in XAML. I don't see how it could be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked if the value present in the collection is not null?
Any non primitive type class is by default null if not constructed with a value.

So you can have as many null values of the type you are trying to have.

I suggest that you do a test by changing the line to:

```
textblock0.Text = App.CurrentlyMappedPhotosets[0].HasValue ? App.CurrentlyMappedPhotosets[0].Value : "";
```

Comment: Interesting; I'll try this out tomorrow morning (that will be my first opportunity to do so).